# Laravel | JQuery UI Datatable sortable - error 500

Tags: jquery, laravel

i have edit.blade.php (artbook view) and inside list of photos (from multiple upload - tables in relationship artbooks 1 : N photos):

```
<div class="dataTables_wrapper">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="table">
      <thead>
        ...
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tablecontents">
        @foreach(($artbook->photos) as $photo)
        @if(!is_null($photo))
        <tr class="row1" data-id="{{ $photo->order }}">
          <td>{{ $photo->order }}</td>
          <td><img class="img-responsive" src="/storage/photos/{{ $photo->filename }}" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/></td>
          <td><a class="btn-dark btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-arrows my-handle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff;"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

in the same view I have script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#table").DataTable();
        $( "#tablecontents" ).sortable({
            items: "tr",
            cursor: 'move',
            opacity: 0.6,
            update: function() {
                sendOrderToServer();
            }
        });
        function sendOrderToServer() {
            var order = [];
            $('tr.row1').each(function(index,element) {
                order.push({
                    id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
                    position: index+1
                });
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                dataType: "json", 
                url: "{{ url('artbook/edit/'.$artbook->id) }}",
                data: {
                    order:order,
                    _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status == "success") {
                        console.log(response);
                    } else {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Function of my ArtbookController:

```
public function updatePhotoOrder(Request $request)
    {
        $photos = Photo::all();  
        console.log('test');
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            $photo->timestamps = false; // To disable update_at field updation
            $id = $photo->id;
            foreach ($request->order as $order) {
                if ($order['id'] == $id) {
                    $photo->update(['order' => $order['position']]);
                }
            }
        }
        return response('Update Successfully.', 200);
    }
```

and here is route:

```
Route::post('artbook/edit/{id}','ArtbookController@updatePhotoOrder');
```

in model my Order field is fillable, and after testing I get an error:

> localhost/artbook/edit/1 500

---

Edit:

```
[2020-09-29 21:53:58] local.ERROR: Use of undefined constant console - assumed 'console' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Use of undefined constant console - assumed 'console' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) at /public_html/app/Http/Controllers/ArtbookController.php:91)
[stacktrace]
#0 /public_html/app/Http/Controllers/ArtbookController.php(91): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Use of undefine...', '/home/fldd/doma...', 91, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\ArtbookController->updatePhotoOrder(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), '1')
```

Can someone help me? So much thanks!

Comment: check the logs to find out why you are getting a 500 error response ... then it will tell you the line where you are trying to use javascript in your PHP file, which you obviously can't do

Comment: It can be problem with route in ajax?

Comment: stop guessing and check the error logs, there is no guessing involved

Comment: I checked. See my edit at the top if you can

Comment: 500 response is an error from the server, check the error logs for the server to find out why the error has been caused ... otherwise you are wasting your time

Comment: There is no information in the error log on the server - about this problem

Comment: what error log did you check?

Comment: Server WWW - Error Log

Comment: how about the laravel log ... but again you are trying to use javascript in your PHP file which you can not do, which is what is probably what is causing the error

Comment: Why can't I? In the list.blade.php view, it works fine. I added laravel log in edit section

Comment: PHP is not javascript ... it is a completely different language with its own syntax ... in your view you are not "executing javascript" it is all just TEXT to be returned (there is no context), your browser is what can understand it as javascript and execute it ... the error gives you the exact line of the problem; no guessing involved

Comment: Sorry, in fact, I typed in php - console.log ('test');

the error is gone but the problem isn;t. I still can't update records in the database (order) after moving element. Now I don't have any logs. And how to find the error ehh

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed the problem:
Changed this:

```
<tr class="row1" data-id="{{ $photo->order }}">
```

to this:

```
<tr class="row1" data-id="{{ $photo->id }}">
```

Thanks lagbox for help!